# gitlab ci/cd piple shell script is not working out of python script

Tags: python, gitlab, git-bash, gitlab-ci-runner

The following script in gitlab ci/cd - but it works locally on runner machine. but when i try in gitlab it shows empty addres list - how tried array and everything its not working

```
script:
   - >
      #!/bin/bash
      cd address;
      echo 'STARTING generate address';
      address_list=$(python3 create_address.py "london"); #output = Name1 address1 
                                                          #         Name2 address2
      echo 'END generate address SUITE ';
      echo "address_list $address_list";
```

address_list is always empty in

Comment: What do you mean "it works locally"? What do you do on your local machine?

Comment: Also please show the code for `create_address.py` or create a simple example to use instead and try to run it with your pipeline.

Comment: A Stack Overflow question needs to contain enough details for someone to reproduce the problem themselves. We don't know what your `create_address.py` does, we don't know what environment variables it depends on, we don't know what variables are actually available in the working vs non-working environments...

Comment: Heck, for all we know the reason it's failing silently without logging an exception to stderr is something like an `except:` handler swallowing the error so it can't be printed. You can't expect answers when you don't provide enough information to let others see the problem themselves so they can test proposed solutions.